amsmath and lmodern incompatibility
I noticed that \usepackage{lmodern} will break amsmath automatic sizing.
Am I doing something wrong? (I thought that Latin Modern was the way to go, for newer documents, but it seems buggy at the moment.)
Below you can see what happens when compiling
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{lmodern}

\showoutput
\begin{document}
  .\vfill Sum \(\sum\).%
  \footnote{Sum \(\sum\).}
\end{document}

with no additional packages, with amsmath, and also with lmodern.



Without packages, we have that LaTeX uses

\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 for "Sum" and
\OMX/cmex/m/n/6 P for "∑" in the main text and
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 for "Sum" and
\OMX/cmex/m/n/6 P for "∑" in the footnote.

Here I can see that the same font size is used for "∑" in the main text and in the footnote.
With amsmath, we have that LaTeX uses

\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 for "Sum" and
\OMX/cmex/m/n/10 P for "∑" in the main text and
\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 for "Sum" and
\OMX/cmex/m/n/8 P for "∑" in the footnote.

This makes no sense. Larger font but smaller glyph in the footnote?
It looks like if the sizing of cmex, the Computer Modern maths extension font, was patched by amsmath.
With amsmath and lmodern, we have that LaTeX uses

\OT1/lmr/m/n/10 for "Sum" and
\OMX/lmex/m/n/6 P for "∑" in the main text and
\OT1/lmr/m/n/8 for "Sum" and
\OMX/lmex/m/n/6 P for "∑" in the footnote.

Here I can see again that the same font size is used for "∑" in the main text and in the footnote.
Logs below
Full logs are provided below for a more detailed inspection of the output.
No packages loaded
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{lmodern}

....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 S
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 u
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 m
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\mathon
....\hbox(0.0+10.00012)x10.55559, shifted -7.50006
.....\OMX/cmex/m/n/6 P
....\mathoff
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 .

....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 S
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 u
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 m
....\glue 2.83337 plus 1.41669 minus 0.94446
....\mathon
....\hbox(0.0+10.00012)x10.55559, shifted -7.00006
.....\OMX/cmex/m/n/6 P
....\mathoff
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 .


The "∑"s have the same height and use the same glyph \OMX/cmex/m/n/6 P.
Load amsmath
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{lmodern}

....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 S
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 u
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 m
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\mathon
....\hbox(0.0+10.00012)x10.55559, shifted -7.50006
.....\OMX/cmex/m/n/10 P
....\mathoff
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 .

....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 S
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 u
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 m
....\glue 2.83337 plus 1.41669 minus 0.94446
....\mathon
....\hbox(0.0+8.0001)x8.97235, shifted -6.00005
.....\OMX/cmex/m/n/8 P
....\mathoff
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/8 .


The glyph for "∑" is \OMX/cmex/m/n/{10,8} P respectively in the main text and in the footnote. The size reflects the surrounding text size (instead of being fixed to 6 points).
Loading amsmath and lmodern
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}

....\OT1/lmr/m/n/10 S
....\OT1/lmr/m/n/10 u
....\OT1/lmr/m/n/10 m
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\mathon
....\hbox(0.0+10.00012)x10.55559, shifted -7.50006
.....\OMX/lmex/m/n/6 P
....\mathoff
....\OT1/lmr/m/n/10 .

....\OT1/lmr/m/n/8 S
....\OT1/lmr/m/n/8 u
....\OT1/lmr/m/n/8 m
....\glue 2.83337 plus 1.41669 minus 0.94446
....\mathon
....\hbox(0.0+10.00012)x10.55559, shifted -7.00006
.....\OMX/lmex/m/n/6 P
....\mathoff
....\OT1/lmr/m/n/8 .


Again, the "∑"s have the same height and use the same glyph \OMX/lmex/m/n/6 P.

Use fixcmex package after lmodern.

I see, that actually worked. Shouldn't this be just added to lmodern package? How are users supposed to know what package need what patch? Also cmex is not lmex… This is even more confusing. Moreover, this package forces the usage of cmex rather than lmex, which undoes what lmodern was trying to do.

@Atcold lmex10 is a straight copy of cmex10. If you want to use it, you have to live with the wrongly sized symbols. I really don't know why the developers didn't copy also the other sizes, that have been available for a long time and stuck to the “fixed” size. At least they should have defined the font as scalable. I wrote fixcmex out of frustration of seeing horribly sized symbols.

I see, thanks @egreg. How about adding your package by default to lmodern? It seems really really bad practice otherwise. Or are there reasons behind not doing this?

@Atcold I'm not responsible for the lmodern package.

Enrico, one of the maintainers Bogusław Jackowski is 75 and the other, Janusz Marian Nowacki, is dead. Who am I supposed to contact to update this package? Also, is it possible to visit you in Verona?
